# upgrading my joomla 2.5 to joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, upgrade, joomla3.0

My site is working on joomla 2.5, I found a lot of new features in joomla 3.3. So I want to move safely to joomla 3.3. I backed up an offline copy of the site to test. What is the right steps to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking a backup and restoring it on a testing environment you've taken the first step on the right direction. You'd be surprised by the amount of people who directly upgrade the production site without testing... and even without backing up.

There are a few things you should do imo:

- First of all, upgrade your site to latest 2.5.x version. At this
  moment it's 2.5.24
- Check ALL your extensions one by one to see if they're 3.3
  compatible. In case they're not, look for a replacement (and for a
  possible way of migrating content from your current one to the new
  one)
- Make sure your testing environment is as similar to the target remote
  server as possible. It's quite usual that you test on a full featured
  local server and then try to restore the site in a very limited
  server, with different MySQL and PHP versions, loading different
  modules...
- Once you have everything working fine in your local testing
  environment, make a test on the remote server to make sure it works
- Check for a 3.3 version of your template. In case there's not one,
  look for a new 3.3 ready template. In this case this is mandatory, as
  you'll have to replace or manually adapt your 2.5 template.

Once you've done all that, you're ready to upgrade. Remember that from 2.5 to 3.3 it's s simple one click operation from Joomla's backend. You can also use 3rd party extensions like Akeeba Admin Tools to help you with the upgrade if you want some extra features.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your interest, but is there an easy way to know that extension is compatible with joomla 3.3 or not ?

Comment: Well, the easiest way is to just launch the upgrade in your test site and check what happens. It's a test site, so you can always restore it again if anything goes really bad. Just one note if you go that way: disable 3rd party system plugins. If one of those is not compatible you might completely break your site.

Another approach could be checking your extensions in JED (easier that going to all author's sites).

Comment: An additional pre-upgrade task is to check magic_quotes_gpc and magic_quotes_runtime are disabled. See http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_turn_off_magic_quotes_gpc_for_Joomla_3 for details.

Comment: You might also consider temporarily disabling the "System - Remember Me" plugin while you upgrade. See http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/244 for details.

Comment: Some extensions (e.g. NoNumber extensions, ChronoForms etc) installed under Joomla 2.5 don't necessarily play well if they suddenly find themselves running on Joomla 3.x. I have worked around this issue by reinstalling extensions over the top of the existing installs immediately after the upgrade. Purging the cache is also a good idea at this point.

Comment: One other thing (last one I promise!), you may need to temporarily change `Components -> Joomla Update -> Options` to "Short Term Support" before you are offered the option to update to Joomla 3.x.